# devenv.exe doesn't unload properly when left open for an extended amount of time

Tags: visual-studio-2010

If I leave Visual Studio 2010 SP1 open for an extended length of time (say, 4+ hours) and then attempt to close it, the solution I am working on is closed and the window goes away, but the process itself never exits and never releases the memory it had claimed. I've disabled all extensions and the problem persists, so I'm inclined to think it's a problem with VS2010, but a quick Google search doesn't turn up any known issues. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This smells like a misbehaving add-in or plugin.  Save your settings and start-up VS using `devenv /resetaddin'.

Optionally, I would save, reset and selectively import my old settings.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running it in **safe mode** (which is everything with original install settings) and see if you get the same problems.

Type this into the *Windows Search bar* OR press *Win + R (*RUN) and *enter || copy/paste:*

**devenv.exe /safemode**